# shorter way to add a string to an existing value inside a table

Tags: php, mysql

let say table `t1` - column `cnt` has value `3,2,5`.

I want to change the value to be `4,3,2,5`.

I'm doing this firstly by selecting the value - creating a variable - and concatenate the string - and update the table.

Is there a shorter way, for example:

```
$sql = "update t1 set cnt = '4,' plus existing value where...;
```

Comment: *column cnt* - what is it's type - varchar, set ?

Comment: @splash58, yes it is a `varchar` type

Comment: In this case, use string function, of couse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below using `concat()` function

```
update t1 set cnt = concat('4,',cnt) 
where...



$sql = "update galls set cnt = concat('$id',',', cnt where...)"
```

Comment: I'm trying to use a variable instead of `4,` - this way - `$sql = "update t1 set cnt = concat('" . $id . ",', cnt where...)";` and getting syntax error, pls help

Comment: syntax error again, but this works - `$sql = "update t1 set cnt = concat('" . $id . ",', cnt) where...";`

Comment: @puerto, glad to know that it workds for u actually I don't know much about php. Anyway, if the sql portion help u would u mind to accept it as an answer :)

Comment: of course, I simply forgot. Thanks a lot for your efforts.